# Cascaded wildcards in a makefile

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I have to build a c project (it is in fact a bit more complicated). This project have some c files that need to be pre-processed with an homemade script. The extension of these files is `.cd`.

So I have this file structure:

```
/project
+ Makefile   
+ foo/
| + foo1.cd
| + foo2.cd
+ bar/
  + bar1.cd
  + bar2.cd
```

Of course, I can add a new folder such as foobar that contains other files. It is worth to say that I cannot have two source files with the same name...

That said, make will do:

```
foo/foo1.cd --> foo/foo1.c
foo/foo1.c  --> obj/foo1.o
...
obj/foo1.o obj/bar1.o ... obj/bar2.o --> a.out
```

Because I have hundreds files. I use wildcards `%` and `vpath` to tell make where it should find them.

To illustrate my issue I wrote this Makefile:

```
OBJDIR = obj
SRCDIR = $(patsubst %/,%,$(sort $(dir $(wildcard ./*/))))

vpath %.c  $(SRCDIR)/
vpath %.cd $(SRCDIR)/
vpath %.o  $(OBJDIR)/

DEFS = $(wildcard ./*/*.cd)   # To be preprocessed
SRCS = $(patsubst %.cd,%.c,$(DEFS)) # Source files
OBJS = $(notdir $(SRCS:.c=.o))      # Objects files

all: a.out

preproc: $(SRCS)

a.out: $(OBJS)
    echo "$^" >> a.out

%.c: %.cd
    echo "$<" >> $@

%.o:%.c
    @if [ ! -f $< ]; then \
        echo "File $< not found" && false;\
    else\
        echo "File $< found ";\
        touch $(OBJDIR)/$@;\
    fi;

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
    -mkdir $(OBJDIR)

clean:
    -rm -f $(SRCS) a.out *.c *.o
    -rm -rf $(OBJDIR)

init: clean
    mkdir -p foo
    mkdir -p bar
    touch foo/foo1.cd
    touch foo/foo2.cd
    touch bar/bar1.cd
    touch bar/bar2.cd
```

First I initialize my example:

```
$ make init
rm -f ./bar/bar2.c ./bar/bar1.c ./foo/foo2.c ./foo/foo1.c  a.out *.c *.o
rm -rf obj
mkdir -p foo
mkdir -p bar
touch foo/foo1.cd
touch foo/foo2.cd
touch bar/bar1.cd
touch bar/bar2.cd
```

Then I need to preproc my files:

```
$ make preproc
echo "bar/bar2.cd" >> bar/bar2.c
echo "bar/bar1.cd" >> bar/bar1.c
echo "foo/foo2.cd" >> foo/foo2.c
echo "foo/foo1.cd" >> foo/foo1.c
```

Finally I build the project:

```
$ make
mkdir obj
File ./bar/bar2.c found
File ./bar/bar1.c found
File ./foo/foo2.c found
File ./foo/foo1.c found
echo "bar2.o bar1.o foo2.o foo1.o" >> a.out
```

The issue is that I need to run make twice. Once to do the preprocessor then another time to build the project. If I try to directly `make all` after the `make init` I will get:

```
$ make
echo "./bar/bar2.cd" >> bar2.c
mkdir obj
File bar2.c found
echo "./bar/bar1.cd" >> bar1.c
File bar1.c found
echo "./foo/foo2.cd" >> foo2.c
File foo2.c found
echo "./foo/foo1.cd" >> foo1.c
File foo1.c found
echo "bar2.o bar1.o foo2.o foo1.o" >> a.out
```

Notice that this time the sources files are put at the root directory not in their supposed location.

I would like to find a solution without the need to run make twice.

Comment: The second question is because make has built-in rules for many common compilation steps. See [Catalogue of Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for the details (also the output from `make -qp -f /dev/null`).

Comment: It will not work to use `vpath` to find built files (like `%.c` or `%.o` above).  You can only correctly use `vpath` to find source files (like `%.cp` above).

Comment: @MadScientist I modified my question with a new makefile. Perhaps we can find a good solution with this new example

Comment: A hacky workaround would be to have the `preproc` target create a file that you `include` into the main makefile so that make runs it automatically and then "restarts" to include it correctly. That might be enough to have make see the generated files but I'm not sure. @MadScientist might know offhand but testing it should be simple enough.

Comment: Do the intermediate (i.e. post-`preproc`) files need to live in the source directory or can they be in the current or output directories?

Comment: @EtanReisner Unfortunately they have to be in the source directory, beside the unprocessed files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.   I also added some other "best practices" to your code.

```
OBJDIR := obj
SRCDIRS := foo bar

vpath %.cd $(SRCDIRS)

DEFS := $(wildcard $(addsuffix  /*.cd, $(SRCDIRS)))     # To be preprocessed
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(notdir $(DEFS:cd=o)))     # Objects files

.PHONY: all
all: a.out 

a.out: $(OBJS) Makefile
    echo $(OBJS) > $@

.PRECIOUS: %.c %/.

%.c: %.cd Makefile
    echo $< > $@

%/.:
    mkdir -p $@


define OBJ_DIR_RECIPE
$1/%.o: $2/%.c Makefile | $1/.
    echo File $$< found
    touch $$@
endef

$(foreach dir, $(SRCDIRS), $(eval $(call OBJ_DIR_RECIPE,$(OBJDIR),$(dir))))
```

Comment: I particulary like the define recipe. I was always looking for something like this. Very nice work ! Thanks. Btw, do you know where I can read a bit more about the "best practices" ?

Comment: @coin yes look at http://make.mad-scientist.net/ Documents/White Papers.  Also look at the examples, especially the whole makefiles, in the Make manual

Answer (score 0):

Both of the patterns in

```
%.o:%.c
```

**match only files in the directory of the Makefile**. I think you should be able to use

```
%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot do that. I have different SRCDIR and I let make find the proper folder to find the correct file.